# how to cast between two custom types

Tags: go

Suppose I have two files.

## hello.go

```
package main


type StringA string


func main() {

    var s StringA
    s = "hello"
    s0 := s.(StringB) <---- somehow cast my StringA to StringB. After all, they are both strings
    s0.Greetings()

}
```

## bye.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type StringB string



func (s StringB) Greetings(){

    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

And compile this like this:

```
go build hello.go bye.go
```

How do I cast `StringA` to the type `StringB`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the way `s0 := StringB(s)` in other languages is a constructor but here is just other way to create compatible types, like `[]byte("abc")`

Your code may looks like:

```
type StringA string

type StringB string

func (s StringB) Greetings(){
    fmt.Println(s)

}

func main() {
    var s StringA
    s = "hello"
    s0 := StringB(s)
    s0.Greetings()
}
```

full example: https://play.golang.org/p/rMzW5FfjSE